# How to replicate the values

Tags: teradata

I want to write a query to duplicate each row based on the value in the repeat column. The input table data looks like as below

```
Products, Repeat
----------------
A,         3
B,         5
C,         2
```

Now in the output data, the product A should be repeated 3 times, B should be repeated 5 times and C should be repeated 2 times. The output will look like as below

```
Products, Repeat
----------------
A,        3
A,        3
A,        3
B,        5
B,        5
B,        5
B,        5
B,        5
C,        2
C,        2
```

Can any body suggest me how to do it in Teradata?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get this result:

#1: classical SQL would be a `JOIN` to a number-table with sequential values `ON n BETWEEN 1 AND Repeat`, depending on the actula data might need a lot of CPU

#2: a Recursive Select, effcient as long as `Repeat` is a small number

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
 (
   SELECT t.*, repeat - 1 AS lvl -- counting down to zero
   FROM tab AS t
   WHERE repeat > 0
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Products, repeat, lvl-1 FROM cte
   WHERE lvl > 0
 )
SELECT Products, repeat_
FROM cte
```

#3: Abusing `EXPAND ON`, proprietary syntax for `PERIOD`, but most efficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
EXPAND ON PERIOD(DATE '2000-01-01', DATE '2000-01-01' + repeat_) AS pd
```

Comment: can u plz explain it using a recursive query?

Comment: @vaibhavkumar: I just added it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help @dnoeth